# Transparent background image, with a different image on each page

Tags: html, css, image

I need to have a transparent background image. With a different image on each page. I have looked at the other answers on here and all of them have me specify the image in the CSS page which doesnt work because then it is on all the pages.

Here is what I have so far

```
#content 
{
padding: 15px 30px 0 0;
}

#main-content 
{
position: relative;
margin-left: 250px;
max-width: 600px;
}

#main-text
{
padding: 10px 15px 19px 15px;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
}

img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.1; 
    z-index: -1;    
}
```

But it is applying the transparency and sizing to all the other images on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just created separate classes for the background images and foreground images.

HTML

```
<img class = "background" src="Images/wheel.png" alt="wheel"/>
```

CSS

```
img.background
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.1; 
    z-index: -1;    
}
```